# How to use a generic class type in combination with a function return type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Why is this type hint not working?

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from dataclasses import dataclass


V = TypeVar('V', int, str)


@dataclass
class Test(Generic[V]):
    a: V


class Base(Generic[V]):
    def test(self) -> Test[V]:
        t = '1'
        return Test[V](t) 


b = Base[str]()
b.test()
```

`mypy` shows:

```
test.py:16: error: Argument 1 to "Test" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
```

My expectation would be that creating the instance `Base` with the specified type `str` it is used for `V` which should be compatible in the `test()` return value as it converts to `Test[str](t)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My expectation would be that creating the instance `Base` with the specified type `str` it is used for `V` which should be compatible in the `test()` return value as it converts to `Test[str](t)`

Your `b = Base[str]()` line has no retroactive effect on the definition of `class Base(Generic[V]):` whatsoever - the definition of `Base.test` simply fails the type check because `t` is `str` (via `t = '1'`), and so what's being returned is `Test[str]` and not a generic `Test[V]` - it's not a way to return "mix" types (see the [`typing.AnyStr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr) as an example and the documentation there has a discussion on this).  Changing that assignment to `t = 1` and to `b = Base[int]()`, mypy will complain about the opposite:

```text
error: Argument 1 to "Test" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
```

Using `pyright` actually gives a somewhat better error message:

```text
  /tmp/so_78174062.py:16:24 - error: Argument of type "Literal['1']"
  cannot be assigned to parameter "a" of type "V@Base" in function "__init__"
    Type "Literal['1']" cannot be assigned to type "V@Base" (reportArgumentType)
```

Which clearly highlights that these are two distinct types (one being a `str` and the other being a [`TypeVar` (type variable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)").

Moreover, using the syntax introduced in [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) may in fact clear up some confusion (refer to the PEP for details); reformatting your example code in that syntax may help make clear what the intent actually is:

```py
@dataclass
class Test[V: (str, int)]:
    a: V

class Base[V: (str, int)]:
    def test(self) -> Test[V: (str, int)]:
        t = 1
        return Test[V: (str, int)](t)

    # or alternatively
    def test2(self) -> Test[V]:
        t = 1
        return Test[V](t)
```

It's a bit more clear that defining a return type `Test[V: (str, int)]` under this paradigm is not sensible, as the return type isn't one of the constrained types (so either `int` or `str`, and not whatever that `V: ...` tries to do). Not to mention that  without the `class` prefixing `Test` pyright interpreted the subsequent `Test[V: (str, int)]` as a `slice` operation which is also nonsensical in that context.  As for `test2`, the `V` is not bound to a concrete type at that context - the `V` in the `class` definition only serves as a placeholder for some concrete type that is defined to be either `int` or `str` which must be defined at the function return type context, so again, invalid.

Based on the given code in the question, the `test` method really should have this signature:

```python
    def test(self) -> Test[str]:
        t = '1'
        return Test[str](t)
```

The above would type check correctly.

---

I noted that the above doesn't actually answer the title of the question: "How to use a generic class type in combination with a function return type?"

Since the above showed that a `TypeVar` is really a type variable, so we can use this where types are allowed. Consider the following:

```
class Base[V: (str, int)]:
    def test(self, t: V) -> Test[V]:
        return Test[V](t)

b = Base[str]()
b.test('1')
c = Base[int]()
c.test(1)
```

Now `b` and `c` are instances the `Base` class with one of the valid type restrictions, and if the argument `t` got substituted for the other type (e.g. swap `1` for `'1'` and vice versa, or even an invalid type), a type validation error will result, as the type `V` would be constrained for the class and the `test` method under either `str` or `int` for instantiations of `Base`.